# select distinct id when using left join and order by on two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, distinct

I have two tables and I am going to get **distinct id from first one** based on a  complex **order by** clauses on both tables. I'm confused how to use **distinct** or **groub by** because both of them prevent using **order by** on other columns.

My code using distinct:

```
select distinct(shops.id) from shops 
left join expiration on shops.id=expiration.shopid 
order by 
  shops.grade desc,
  expiration.startdate asc,
  expiration.enddate desc,
  shops.id
```

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is
>   specified

My code using group by:

```
select max(shops.id) as shopid from shops 
left join expiration on shops.id=expiration.shopid
group by shopid
order by 
  shops.grade desc,
  expiration.startdate asc,
  expiration.enddate desc,
  shops.id
```

> Column "shops.grade" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is
>   not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: There can be more than one `expiration.startdate` for one `shops.id`? If yes, then how it should be sorted according to the lowest or how? If no, then add it to the `group by`.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is **not a function**. It's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT` and applies to the whole selected rows. Skip those redundant parentheses and simply write `select distinct shops.id from shops ...` to make things clearer.

Comment: Your `LEFT JOIN`s in both queries aren't doing anything, and don't seem to have any bearing on the values you're selecting from `shops`. If what you really want is a list of the distinct shop ids, use `SELECT DISTINCT shopid = id FROM shops`. and if you want the largest id value, just use `SELECT MAX(id) FROM shops`. No need for the joins here.

Comment: I use join for ordering by columns in another table @digital.aaron

Comment: Can you post a more complete query, then? Your examples aren't utilizing any columns from expiration. Do you have any sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregate functions in `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT shops.id AS shopid -- No need to use MAX(...) here
FROM shops 
LEFT JOIN expiration ON shops.id=expiration.shopid
GROUP BY shopid
ORDER BY
  MAX(shops.grade) DESC,
  MIN(expiration.startdate) ASC,
  MAX(expiration.enddate) DESC,
  shops.id
```

Comment: Thank you it worked. how can I use this kind of aggregators when I am ordering also on null and non null valuses. I mean aggregator on `case when expiration.startdate is null then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: @AliSheikhpour You can put `CASE` expressions into aggregating functions, e.g. `MAX(CASE WHEN ... END)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have a prioritization query.  If so, you can handle it with `row_number()` not `select distinct` or `group by`:

```
select se.shopid
from (select s.id as shopid,
             row_number() over (partition by s.id
                                order by s.grade desc, e.startdate asc, e.enddate desc, s.id
                               ) as seqnum
      from shops s left join
           expiration e
           on s.id = e.shopid
     ) se
where seqnum = 1;
```